# Format number as the exact seconds part of a time specification

Tags: formatting

I am trying to print a number with padding using the function `NumberForm` in order to get the number format like `"01.1234567"` where there are 9 significant digits with 7 to the right of the decimal point.  This is meant to be similar to the seconds part of a time specification such as `"01:15:01.123467"`. I would have thought this function would achieve the result but I seem to get an extra padded `"0"` to the left:

```
ToString@NumberForm[1.1234567, {9, 7}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]
```

but instead it returns:

> 001.1234567

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can get the result `"01.1234567"` using this function or is this a bug and I need to trying an alternative?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `"0"` is added by the default `NumberSigns -> {"-",""}` option. You can remove it by setting `NumberSigns -> {"",""}`, but then negative numbers will be displayed without the minus sign:

```
NumberForm[-1.1234567, {9, 7}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]
NumberForm[1.1234567, {9, 7}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}]
NumberForm[-1.1234567, {9, 7}, NumberPadding -> {"0", "0"}, NumberSigns -> {"", ""}]
```

> 0-1.1234567
>
> 001.1234567
>
> 01.1234567

This aspect of behavior of `NumberForm` isn't documented AFAIK.

Comment: Many thanks!!!!